# What is the name of the horizontal bar that intersects a window mullion?

Tags: meaning

Mullioned windows are windows divided into panes by inner frames. The vertical frames are called mullions. What do we call the horizontal frames?

Comment: Many architectural terms vary between countries. It would be good to know if you're more interested in the usage in the UK, the US, or some other country?

Comment: Please provide a picture of what exactly you are asking about.  The correct answer depends on us knowing precisely which it is.

Comment: @ThePhoton Thanks If there are many I want to know them all -- with their countries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Transom** according to Wikipedia, which says "In architecture, a transom is a transverse horizontal structural beam or bar, or a crosspiece separating a door from a window above it. This contrasts with a mullion, a vertical structural member." Sadly I can't find a more authoritative source although various glazing/window/building companies use the term, e.g. [Architonic](https://www.architonic.com/en/products/mullion-transom-facades/0/3246876/1), [Thames Valley windows](https://www.tvwindows.com/blog/window-mullions-and-transoms).

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mullion
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transom_(architecture)

Answer (score 2):

In the usage I'm familiar with (doing some home restoration in the western US), the members dividing individual panes of glass (whether vertical or horizontal) are *muntins*.

I hadn't run into the term *mullion* before, but apparently it is used for vertical members that separate sashes or casements.

In paneled (rather than glazed) doors, the horizontal members dividing the panels are *rails* and the vertical members are *stiles*. The larger horizontal members of a sash may also be called *rails*.

[image]

Image source: Twitter user [@tylor](https://twitter.com/tylorsherman/status/670541071185678336)

[image]

Image source: [City of Burlington (WI) Historic District](https://www.burlington-wi.gov/DocumentCenter/View/1740/HPC-Facade-Grant---COA-Application-2020-filable?bidId=)

Answer (score 1):

In the UK it is a **transom**.

This [Home Heroes](https://www.home-heroes.co.uk/whats-a-mullion-i-thought-that-was-a-muntin-isnt-that-a-glazing-bar-so-whats-a-transom/) (regulated by the Royal Institution of Chartered Surveyors) website states

> Interestingly in America it is not uncommon for a horizontal member within a window to be called a mullion as well over here **in England we tend to use the term transom** to describe the horizontal members in windows.

Here is a reference from [Sheerwater Glass](https://www.sheerwaterglass.co.uk/blog/window-mullions-and-transoms/)

> **What is a window transom?**
>
> A transom is a horizontal beam that is paired with a mullion that divides a window’s upper part into additional lights. When transoms are positioned, generally they will be placed above head height to avoid obstructing the view from a window.

The **transom** (horizontal) and **mullion** (vertical) are *structural* components, as distinct from the **glazing bars** (UK) or **muntins** (US) which serve to separate, and act as a bed for, the individual panes of glass.

Comment: Why the downvote? I quote credible sources, to back up my knowledge of 9 years in the building industry.

Comment: Don't know the reason for the downvote either, but, +1.

Comment: Thank you for that @Justin.

Comment: One from me too. I didn't give you the green tick because Stuart came in first.

Comment: Thanks, I saw it come and go, but that is fair.